# Link getElementsByTagName calls to traverse DOM for items you need

Tags: javascript

I have a page with a bunch of paragraphs. Each paragraph has an href that i want. However I dont want ALL the hrefs on the page, just the ones in the body ->p ->href.

How can I do this in javascript?

I want to do something like this, but it is wrong:

```
var myList = document.body.getElementsByTagName("p.href");
```

Note: I don't want to have to iterate over all p elements and extract the href, I just want to limit the scope of the hrefs.

sample input:

```
<p> <a href....></a></p>
```

Comment: _"Each paragraph has an href"_. Then you have invalid HTML.

Comment: @j08691 - Didn't see your comment, and didn't notice the paragraph part, I guess one assumes it's anchors when they have href attributes

Comment: Please no smart comments, just looking for help here. <p> <a href....></a></p>

Comment: @adeneo - OP updated the question. Looks like his HTML was valid (even though the description would lead one to think otherwise).

Comment: @j08691 - yup, undeleted my answer, as that should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In newer browsers :

```
document.querySelectorAll('p a[href="someLink"]')
```

or

```
var p   = document.getElementsByTagName('p'),
    arr = [];

for (var j=p.length; j--;) {
    var a = p[j].getElementsByTagName('a'),
    for (var i=a.length; i--;) {
        arr.push( a[i].href );
    }
}
```

Comment: this seems like the right approach. What if I dont know the href, can I just do 'p a[href=*]'

Comment: Do you have anchors that don't have a href attribute, if not, just drop the href and select all the anchors

Comment: so I will always have to iterate? I can't just get an array of hrefs already without having to go through each a tag and pull it out?

Comment: Nope, you have to iterate over the elements to get each elements href attribute

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have links (`<a>` tags  inside the `<p>` elements)...

You can do it with jquery like this:

```
var links = $('p a');
```

or like this if you want only direct children (not further descendants):

```
var links = $('p > a');
```

Or with pure javascript you'd have to loop through:

```
var paragraphs = document.body.getElementsByTagName("p");
for (var i=0;i<paragraphs .length;i++)
{ 
    var links = paragraphs[i].getElementsByTagName("a");
    // This is only the links in this paragraph, so you would need to add to a global list if you want to keep track of all of them in one place
}
```

If you want to get the href attribute from a link element, you can do it like this:

```
var link0href = links[0].href;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well as @j08691 stated if your `p` elements have a href attribute they are invalid.

The following will get the href of an item where `0` is the index of an item
`document.body.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].href`